# VBScript CopyHere Function Stalling

Tags: windows-10, zip, vbscript

I have a script to extract the contents of a .zip folder that isn't working (code at bottom of post, for reference).  I create a destination folder if it doesn't exist, then use CopyHere to move the contents to the destination folder.  The script runs to the point where it creates a folder, then appears to stall during the CopyHere function (nothing is ever moved from the zip file).  Note that the Windows Based Script Host process is running indefinitely at this point and I have to manually terminate it.

It seems to be something specific with my machine, as the script runs in a virtual machine I have, as well as other coworkers' machines (all x64 Windows 10 Professional).

I have full privileges in the location I am trying to extract to, so I don't believe it's a permissions issue.  The only difference between the machines that I can think of is I installed the Ubuntu-in-Windows feature to play around.  Maybe that is causing an issue?

What other steps can I take to figure out why the process is stalling?

Thanks!

-Sean

```vb
Function unzip(sZip)

    Dim oFSO, oShell
    dim zip, d

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    sZipFile = oFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(sZip)
    sDestPath = oFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(Left(sZip, Len(sZip) - 4))

    If Not oFSO.FolderExists(sDestPath) Then
        oFSO.CreateFolder(sDestPath)
    End If

    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set zip = oShell.NameSpace(sZipFile)
    set d = oShell.NameSpace(sDestPath)

    MsgBox "Got here"

    d.CopyHere zip.items, 256

    Set oFSO = Nothing
    Set oShell = Nothing

End Function

Dim oFSO
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

sPath = oFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)

sInstPath = sPath & "\dist\installers\"
aInsts = Array("4-AgilentIOLib.zip", "5-NationalInstrumentsLib.zip")

For i = 0 To UBound(aInsts)

    MsgBox "Unzipping " & sInstPath & aInsts(i)

    unzip(sInstPath & aInsts(i))

    MsgBox "Done"
Next
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you can easily debug your script by using the Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. I have wrote a tip how to do it: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/864659/How-to-Debug-Visual-Basic-Script-with-Visual-Studi Try to go in debugger row by row in order to find the problem!

Comment: Verify that the zip file is not corrupt.

Comment: Unfortunately the debugger didn't give much info.  The process eventually starts, it just takes up to 20 minutes on certain machines at my office.

Answer (score 0):

`CopyHere` is using the `256` option, which is `Display a progress dialog box but do not show the file names.`
[source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-copyhere)

Is it possible you're getting a prompt you're not seeing? Are you running the script with `wscript.exe` or `cscript.exe`? Are you running it interactively?

Can you try with option `4`, to not display a progress dialog? You could also try `16+256` which would add `Respond with "Yes to All" for any dialog box that is displayed.`

I also ran the script and it works fine, but when I reran it I got prompted to overwrite existing files.

Comment: I tried both options you mentioned.  Unfortunately the same thing happens.  It does eventually start (~15-20 minutes later).  I am thinking that I am just going to include the mass of files in the installer, rather than a zip.  Then I can xcopy from the temp directory to where they need to be.